# set value with datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

How can I set value with datepicker in this code.
Property get is ok but I have a problem with property set if I change value datepicker in my application
it's nothing happening.

```
public DateTime FirstRegistration
{
    get
    {
        return _firstRegistration;
    }
    set
    {
        _firstRegistration = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstRegistration));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DatePicker Text="{Binding FirstRegistration}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Width="200"  
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="First registration" FontSize="18" 
    Background="White" Style="{StaticResourceMaterialDesignFloatingHintDatePicker}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to bind `SelectedDate` property on the `DatePicker` instead of Text.

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding FirstRegistration}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Width="200"  
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="First registration" FontSize="18" 
    Background="White" Style="{StaticResourceMaterialDesignFloatingHintDatePicker}"/>
```